# Rectification matrix clarification in stereo vision calibration

Tags: ros, stereo-camera, stereo, stere-image-proc, stereo-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a Point Grey Bumblebee2 that I am trying to integrate into ROS and I am using the camera1394stereo node to read raw images from both cameras.

I have calibrated both cameras by hand and am currently trying to figure out how to configure the yaml files as specified in the StereoCalibration tutorial

So far, I have successfully undistorted the images.  However, I am very unclear about what values I should put down in the rectification matrix.  What is contained in this matrix?  Is it a rotation matrix of the two cameras orientations with respect to each other?

I have been trying to insert rotations matrices into these values, only to encounter segfaults.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59620/rectification-matrix-clarification-in-stereo-vision-calibration/) by [mortonjt](https://answers.ros.org/users/4408/mortonjt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 217 on 2013-03-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the [CameraInfo](http://ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/CameraInfo.html) message declaration:

> Rectification matrix (stereo cameras
> only) A rotation matrix aligning the
> camera coordinate system to the ideal
> stereo image plane so that epipolar
> lines in both stereo images are
> parallel.

Alternatively, ROS has a tool built in to do stereo calibration and write it out in the correct format: http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera_calibration/Tutorials/StereoCalibration

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2013-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mortonjt](https://answers.ros.org/users/4408/mortonjt/) on 2013-04-01**:
Perfect!  Thanks for the link

**Comment by [mortonjt](https://answers.ros.org/users/4408/mortonjt/) on 2013-04-08**:
Actually the reason why I tried to calibrate the cameras by hand is because I've had so much trouble using the built in ROS stereo calibration software. http://answers.ros.org/question/60177/cameracalibratorpy-crashes-during-calibration/ .  Have you ever had this problem?